# How do I make pip display the latest version of a package on PyPI?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

How can I make pip show the latest version of a package on PyPI? When I search for a package, no version information is shown.

For example:

```
> pip search aiozmq
aiozmq                    - ZeroMQ integration with asyncio.
```

Comment: Do you want to know what's the latest version, or if there is an upgrade to the one you have installed?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid As the question says, just the latest version of the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such option in pip. pip will only tell you if installed packages have an update available, with `pip list -o`

You can use `yolk`, however to get the latest version number:

```
$ yolk -V aiozmq | head
aiozmq 0.5.0
```

Install `yolk`, or `yolk3k` (for Python 3 compatibility) with .... `pip install yolk`.

Answer (score 2):

The `pip index` command can be used to display the latest version and list all the available versions.

```
$ pip index versions aiozmq
aiozmq (1.0.0)
Available versions: 1.0.0, 0.9.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.3, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.0, 0.2.0, 0.1.3, 0.1.2, 0.1.1, 0.1.0
```